# Problema con php en la linea 11

Tags: php, mysqli

en el siguiente codigo me da un error en la linea 11

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('<h1>Servidor not found</h1>');
    $db = mysqli_select_db($link, 'dama') or die('<h1>Error de conexion</h1>');

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellidos'];

    $req = (strlen($nombre)*strlen($apellido) or die('No se han llenado todos los campos'));

    //inserta los valores en la base de datos
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES ('', '$nombre', '$apellido')", $link) or die('<h2>Error de envio</h2>');
    echo '
        <h2>Registro completado</h2>
        <a href="../inicio_sesion.php">inicia sesion</a>
    ';
?>
```

en el mysqli_query. agradeceria una respuesta

El error que muestra es el siguiente:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #1 ($mysql)
> must be of type mysqli, string given in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app-php\database\index2.php:11 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app-php\database\index2.php(11): mysqli_query('INSERT
> INTO usu...', Object(mysqli)) #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app-php\database\index2.php on line 11

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En efecto, el error debe estar en la variable link, pues [mysqli_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php) espera 4 parámetros (host, usuario, contraseña y la BD)

Prueba de esta forma:

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dama') or die('<h1>Servidor not found</h1>');


    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellidos'];

    $req = (strlen($nombre)*strlen($apellido) or die('No se han llenado todos los campos'));

    //inserta los valores en la base de datos
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido')") or die('<h2>Error de envio</h2>');
    echo '
        <h2>Registro completado</h2>
        <a href="../inicio_sesion.php">inicia sesion</a>
    ';
?>
```

Comment: En efecto esto mejora la mantenibilidad porque evita que cambios en la tabla hagan fallar la consulta (si añaden columnas, por ejemplo). Pero no es olbigatorio indicar los campos si uno usa TODOS los campos.

Comment: he corregido el error como me has indicado y me sigue dando error.

Comment: En este caso, edita la pregunta y coloca que error te da

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\app-php\database\index2.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\app-php\database\index2.php(11): mysqli_query('INSERT INTO usu...', Object(mysqli)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\app-php\database\index2.php on line 11

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en la variable link

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, revisa si eso te funciona

Comment: ya me funcionó. gracias

Comment: Entonces mejor aprueba la respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación la conexión va primero.

```
mysqli_query(mysqli $link, string $query);
```